# extendscript after effects if else statement how do i fix this up

Tags: extendscript

this is my code the else statement is not firing well.

 just test it if you can type in any effect and name it. I am trying to get the else statement to work check=false so that I can add my other action code to it.

```
var effectNameCollection = app.effects;
var check = false;
for (var i = 0; i < effectNameCollection.length; i++) {
    var name = effectNameCollection[i].displayName;
    if (name == "Color Matcher") {
        check = true;
    alert ("INSTALLED");

}else{
alert ("not installed");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is. But I will happily lend some advice. First of all, you likely don't want to have your `alert` code to be inside of the the for-loop. The way you have it now, it will fire an alert on every loop. I have 428 effects installed on my After-Effects, so that is a lot of alerts!

```js
var effectNameCollection = app.effects;
var check = false;
for (var i = 0; i < effectNameCollection.length; i++) {
    var name = effectNameCollection[i].displayName;
    $.writeln(name);
    if (name == "Color Matcher") {
        check = true;
    }
}

var chckAlert = check ? "INSTALLED" : "not installed";
alert(chckAlert);
```

The code above will log all of your installed effects to the terminal using `$.writeln` (extendscript's version of a console.log) and then will alert you if an effect with the name of 'Color Matcher' is installed.

The line:
`var chckAlert = check ? "INSTALLED" : "not installed";`
is just a condensed version of an if-else statement and is equivalent to:

```js
var chckAlert = '';

if (check) {
    chckAlert = "INSTALLED";
} else {
    chckAlert = "not installed";`
}
```